# How erp on cloud works?

Tags: erp

Anyone can tell me briefly how erp works on the cloud? Also want to know the vendor list who can provide the erp solution?

Answer (score 3):

This is a bit of a general answer that may not apply to all vendors.

Traditional ERP systems will have a database that resides on an onsite server. Each user will have a client program installed on their computer that communicates with this database. A cloud ERP system will most likely have a database at a remote datacenter. There will be a webserver running a website that provides the erp functions. End users will use a web browser access the erp website. An analogy with email apps would be outlook vs gmail.

The advantages of the cloud system

- Don't need to pay for servers or database licenses
- (probably) don't need to worry about data backups
- Software updates centralised on webserver.

disadvantages

- speed of internet connection will probably be a bottleneck. ERP systems can generate a lot of network traffic if you run lots of reporting or have lots users. You will need to check if your current connection will handle it.
- Consider what happens if you stop paying for maintainance. you may lose access to your data. With traditional ERP you will still have the database and probably use of the software with no further updates.

Unfortunately I don't have a list of vendors for cloud based systems.